# Change a value on another worksheet based on a checkbox check

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

After some searching and trying to figure it out my self i'm stumped. I could use some help on this one.

I have an excel workbook that has multiple tabs. The two I need help with is the "KronosEntries" and the "MASTER" tab. The MASTER tab has a list of all the missed days and vacation time for the employee. The KronosEntries tab has a list of all the records from the MASTER tab that need to be entered into Kronos. Once they are entered into Kronos I will check the box next to that line to remove it from the KronosEntries tab. When I add a new line on the MASTER tab it automatically adds a "No" in column R. What I want to happen is when I check the checkbox on the KronosEntries tab I want to change column R on the MASTER tab to "Yes" for the row that has the same data.

Here's the KronosEntries tab example.

[image: KronosEntries]

Here's the MASTER tab example.

[image: MasterTab]

Here's what I used to add the checkboxes.

```
Sub Addcheckboxes()

'Declare variables and data types
Dim cell, LRow As Single
Dim ChkBx As CheckBox
Dim CLeft, CTop, CHeight, CWidth As Double

'Don't refresh or update screen while processing macro, this will make the macro quicker.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Find last non empty cell in column A
LRow = Worksheets("KronosEntries").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Iterate through 2 to last non empty cell
For cell = 2 To LRow

    'Check if cell in column B is not equal to nothing
    If Cells(cell, "B").value <> "" And Cells(cell, "B").value <> "Employee ID" Then

        'Save cell dimensions and coordinates of corresponding cell in column E to variables
        CLeft = Cells(cell, "A").Left
        CTop = Cells(cell, "A").Top
        CHeight = Cells(cell, "A").Height
        CWidth = Cells(cell, "A").Width

        'Create checkbox based on dimension and coordinates data from variables
        Worksheets("KronosEntries").CheckBoxes.Add(CLeft, CTop, CWidth, CHeight).Select

        With Selection
            .Caption = ""
            .value = xlOff
            .LinkedCell = .TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 8).Address
            .Display3DShading = False
        End With

    End If

    Next cell

    Worksheets("KronosEntries").Range("A6").Select

    'Turn on screen refresh
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Here's what I used to remove the checkboxes.

```
Sub RemoveCheckboxes()

    'Declare variables and data types
    Dim ChkBx As CheckBox

    'Iterate through all check boxes on active sheet
    For Each ChkBx In Worksheets("KronosEntries").CheckBoxes

        'Remove checkbox
        ChkBx.Delete

    'Continue with next checkbox
    Next

End Sub
```

The part I cant seem to sort out is the code to change column R to Yes for the row that has the same data. Can someone help? Thank you

I put the latest code that I cant get working below. Not even sure if i'm on the right track. I'm calling the ChangeData sub on Worksheet_Calculate.

```
Sub ChangeData

For Each ChkBx In Worksheets("KronosEntries").CheckBoxes

'If check box is enabled
If ChkBx.value = 1 Then

    'Go through each row on worksheet
    For r = 1 To Rows.Count

        'Check if checkbox is on the same row
        If Cells(r, 1).Top = ChkBx.Top Then

            'Sheet to change value in.
            With Worksheets("MASTER")

               Worksheets("MASTER").Range("R" & r) = Worksheets("KronosEntries").Range("L" & r).value

               End With

               'Exit For Loop
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: you are essentially asking us to write code for you without showing the effort you already put in - having that code that you have tried would probably help us help you because there are some ambiguities. That said, you'll need to write code based on the change event of the checkbox.

Comment: I dropped in what I have so far but haven't been able to get it working. I've changed it many times. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach when adding the data from the MASTER tab to the KronosEntries tab. I scratched the old code and used the following.

btw, I'm sure there's a better way to do this but this is working fine.

So on Userform button click I added. (This will save the needed data on each tab)

```
Private Sub AddViolationSave_Click()

            'This adds the data to the MASTER worksheet.
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER")
            Dim tbl As ListObject
            'This sets the table to read from.
            Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("MasterList")
            Dim newrow As ListRow
            Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add

                With newrow
                'This will add the values needed. The other formulas will automatically fill in. (Range 1 equals cell 1 in the first row)
                .Range(1) = AddEmployeeID.value
                .Range(2) = ComboBox6.value
                .Range(3) = PaidComboBox.value
                .Range(4) = ReasonComboBox.value
                .Range(5) = TypeComboBox.value
                .Range(7) = DateBox.value
                .Range(8) = ChargedComboBox.value
                .Range(9) = PointsComboBox.value
                .Range(10) = Sheets("Database").Range("A91").value
                End With

           'This code will add the data to the KronosEntries tab.
            Dim ws2 As Worksheet
            Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("KronosEntries")
            Dim tbl2 As ListObject
            'This sets the table to read from.
            Set tbl2 = ws2.ListObjects("KronosTable")
            Dim newrow2 As ListRow
            Set newrow2 = tbl2.ListRows.Add

                With newrow2
                'This will add the values needed. The other formulas will automatically fill in. (Range 1 equals cell 1 in the first row)
                .Range(2) = AddEmployeeID.value
                .Range(3) = ComboBox6.value
                .Range(4) = ReasonComboBox.value
                .Range(5) = TypeComboBox.value
                .Range(6) = Sheets("Database").Range("N9").Formula
                .Range(7) = DateBox.value
                End With

            Call Addcheckboxes

            'we will delete the empty lines fromt he table here.
            Dim Rng As Range
            On Error Resume Next
            Set Rng = Range("KronosTable[[Employee ID]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If

        MsgBox "New record successfully added.", vbOK + vbExclamation, "Record Added"

End Sub
```

Then for the change data sub I used this in a module along with the AddCheckBoxes & RemoveCheckBoxes above.

```
Sub ChangeData()

    'Go through each check box in active sheet
    For Each ChkBx In Worksheets("KronosEntries").CheckBoxes

    'If check box is enabled
    If ChkBx.value = 1 Then

        'Go through each row on worksheet
        For r = 1 To Rows.Count

            'Check if checkbox is on the same row
            If Cells(r, 1).Top = ChkBx.Top Then

                'Will clear the contents of the row where the checkbox is checked.
                Range(ChkBx.LinkedCell).EntireRow.Range("A1:G1").ClearContents
                'Will uncheck the checkbox
                ChkBx.value = -4146

                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
    End If
    Next

    RemoveCheckboxes

    Addcheckboxes

    'This will delete the lines with no data.
    Dim Rng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rng = Range("KronosTable[[Employee ID]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If

End Sub
```